# Building Perf with Babeltrace (for Perf to CTF Conversion) fails with undefined reference to bt_ctf_validate_identifier

Tags: linux, perf

I followed instructions provided by the existing Stackoverflow question/answer [Building Perf with Babeltrace (for Perf to CTF Conversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576997/building-perf-with-babeltrace-for-perf-to-ctf-conversion)

Building linux/tools/perf with Babeltrace conversion support fails with the following error:

LINK     perf
`libperf.a(libperf-in.o): In function event_class_add_field:
/tools/perf/util/data-convert-bt.c:988: undefined reference to bt_ctf_validate_identifier
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.perf:567: recipe for target 'perf' failed`

I tried building linux/tools/perf with Babeltrace installed from packages on Debian Linux distribution and also building Babeltrace from source code.

In both cases, Babeltrace was successfully installed and available before an attempt at building linux/tools/perf with Babeltrace CTF support.

Comment: Babeltrace built from source code, git tag -l displays: v2.0.0-pre4

Comment: I get the same error when building linux/tools/perf on Linux source code versions 4.20 and 4.15.0.

Comment: Building linux/tools/perf with: `NO_LIBBABELTRACE=1 make`

Results in a working perf binary.

Comment: Can you try to build with older version of Babeltrace, with checking that this version has `bt_ctf_validate_identifier` function? For example you may try versions from 2017 when the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576997/ was asked or v1.5.6 or v1.5.3. Where is the git of babeltrace? The function `bt_ctf_validate_identifier` was added in 2015 [654c1444](https://github.com/efficios/babeltrace/commit/654c1444b546fd79b209288b93ed4e87d9bb8a2b) to `formats/ctf/ir/utils.c` file which is part of v1.5.6 but not 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

`bt_ctf_validate_identifier` function seems to be defined and implemented only in 1.5 branch of the babeltrace, not in 2.0 (v2.0.0-pre4)

https://github.com/efficios/babeltrace/blob/stable-1.5/formats/ctf/ir/utils.c
https://github.com/efficios/babeltrace/blob/v1.5.6/formats/ctf/ir/utils.c

```
75   int bt_ctf_validate_identifier(const char *input_string)
```

Try to recompile and reinstall babeltrace from git tag `v1.5.6` and then clean and recompile perf with this version.

perf tool from linux kernel versions 4.15 - 4.20 seems to be written for stable-1.5 branches of the babeltrace.